# Unable to Locate specific JDK on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I'm starting up a new project in Intellij IDEA and when I go to select a JDK all that shows up is JDK 16.0.1 and I need JDK 8 (already installed) So I click "add JDK..." I browse through my files and I'm only able to locate JDK 16. NOTE: JDK 8 is on my desktop

Comment: _"JDK 8 is on my desktop"_ exactly what do you mean with that? The JDK is - normally - not installed in your desktop. So, if this is some shortcut, check its target, if it is an installer, you will first need to run that installer.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple JDK environment variables cannot be configured on the same computer at the same time, but we can change the value to the corresponding JDK installation directory by modifying JAVA_HOME in the JDK environment variable:[image]

Comment: *"Multiple JDK environment variables cannot be configured on the same computer at the same time ... "* -  Not correct.  Different user accounts have their own env variables.

Comment: And in fact, each command interpreter instance (e.g. cmd.exe) will have its own set of environment variables.  So you can set `JAVA_HOME` in a batch file, and it will only affect executions of that specific batch file.